# как установить npm в docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, dockerfile

есть docker-compose.yaml
version: '2'
services:

```
 nginx:
  build: nginx
  container_name: nginx
  ports: 
    - 80:80
    - 443:443
  volumes: 
    - ./:/usr/share/nginx/html

 php-fpm:
  image: nanoninja/php-fpm
  container_name: php-fpm
  volumes:
    - ./:/usr/share/nginx/html

 db:
  container_name: mysql
  image: mysql
  restart: always
  environment:
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
    - MYSQL_USER=test
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test

 phpmyadmin:
  container_name: phpmyadmin
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  links:
    - db
  ports:
    - 8080:80

 frontend:
  build: frontend
  container_name: frontend
  volumes:
    - ./:/usr/share/frontend
```

Вот к контейнеру docker file

```
   FROM node

   RUN mkdir /usr/share/frontend
   WORKDIR /usr/share/frontend

   COPY package.json /usr/share/frontend/package.json

   RUN npm install

   CMD ["npm","start"]
```

На 4 шаге выдает следующую ошибку:

> Step 4/7 : COPY package.json /usr/share/frontend/package.json ERROR:
>   Service 'frontend' failed to build: lstat package.json: no such file
>   or directory

Comment: пожалуйста, нажмите править вопрос и добавьте ваши настройки в виде ТЕКСТА.

Comment: на самом деле вам нужно Dockerfile перенести в корень проекта рядом с  package.json. А проблема возникает из-за того, что вы относительно папки, где находится Dockerfile пытаетесь копировать файл package.json, который на самом деле находится на 2 уровня выше

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, переместил в корень проекта и теперь такая ошибка ~/docker$ docker-compose up -d --build
ERROR: build path /home/vitaly/docker/frontend either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, подскажи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поправь `COPY` - `COPY package.json* /usr/share/frontend/`. `*` - нужно для `package-lock.json`. И внимательно читаем про [build directive](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#build).

```
build: frontend # это директория root для сборки
```

надо

```
build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: Dockerfile # путь до Dockerfile
```

Поэтому `COPY package.json` не работает - нету файла.

Используй версию api version 3 - `links` плохая практика.